# Android: OnActivityResult behavior

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, startactivityforresult

I am using `startActivityForResult` in my application. But I have some doubts/queries about its behavior.

**Scenario:** In my application. I have two activities, say Activity1 and Activity2. I am calling `startActivityForResult` from my Activity1 to Activity2 twice with different request codes.

```
final REQUEST_CODE_1 = 1;
final REQUEST_CODE_2 = 2;

Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_1);
```

and

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_2);
```

And I get the data back in `onActivityResult`

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (data != null) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_1:
                //some piece of code
                break;
            case REQUEST_CODE_2:
                //some piece of code
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

And in my Activity2, I have some condition based on which it sends the data back 
to Activity1.

```
myStr = scanner.getValue();
if(myStr.startsWith("5901")){
     intent.putExtra("box",myStr);
     setResult(REQUEST_CODE_1,intent);
  }else{
      intent.putExtra("item",myStr+"dCbA");
      setResult(REQUEST_CODE_2,intent);
}
```

where `mystr` is a String variable.

**Problem:**  From Activity1, I execute the 1st code i.e with `REQUEST_CODE_1` and in my Activity2, the else block is executed. In this case, I expect `REQUEST_CODE_2` to come back to Activity, but instead, I get `REQUEST_CODE_1` back to Activity. Clearly, the `setResult` of `else` block didn't execute as intended.

I hope my question is clear.
Can someone please explain.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add to your question the values set for both REQUEST constants. And also how myStr value is assigned a value to switch between both request codes.

Comment: what are the values of REQUEST_CODE_1 and REQUEST_CODE_2 ?

Comment: @Juan I have updated my question

Comment: @0X0nosugar I have updated my question

Comment: Also add a Log.d to get the value of myStr before going into the if statemente. Just to be sure the problem is not in the value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I look, you suppose that myStr is the request_code sent from Activity1.

The request_code is not part of the arguments, so you need to add it to the Intent.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
i.putExtra("request_code", REQUEST_CODE_1);
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_1);
```

So you can get it from the Activity2 with getArguments().getIntegerExtra("request_code")

And in this case, you need to compare the object with another literal without equals (or wrapper)

Also, Activity2 doesn't need to know the integer to setResult, as it need to be one of RESULT_OK, RESULT_CANCELED, RESULT_NONE. The onActivityResult will receive back (requestCode, resultCode, data) where requestCode will be exactly the integer you did startActivityForResult and resultCode will be the one set in Activity2 before finishing.

Comment: Hi there,
I have updated my question, maybe it is clearer now

Comment: you  need to switch on requestCode not on resultCode

Comment: Cause in your code, you can start with any REQUEST_CODE but according to the different RESULT_CODES you will get different results.

Comment: I have two completely functions to call... if I use the switch-case on resultCode, i will get OK, CANCELED or NONE.... fine, but I will have to use requestCode also to know for which request I am getting this result and parse... so I have to use `if(requestCode ==REQUEST_1 && resultCode ==RESULT_OK{ --- }`. Am I right?

Comment: yes, the requestCode will be EXACTLY the same you send to open other acitvity, the resultCode is set in the secondary activity

Answer (score 1):

setResult(int) must always supply a result code, which can be the standard results RESULT_CANCELED, RESULT_OK. You are supplying the request code instead of RESULT_OK or RESULT_CANCELED.

Try this

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_1);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (data != null) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_1:
                //check if resultCode is RESULT_OK or CANCELED
                break;
            case REQUEST_CODE_2:
                //some piece of code
                break;
        }
    }

}


if(myStr.startsWith("5901")){
     setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
  }else{
      setResult(RESLT_CANCELED,intent);
}
```